# Fitting an image and corresponding span to parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div of fixed width and height.
I want to put and image and caption to it (using img and figurecaption) such that they both never exceeds the dimensions of the parent.

I tried this : 
`

```
parent-> 
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0;
img->
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
figurecaption->
text-align: center
```

`

When the image is of greater size than the specified height and width, the caption goes outside. How to deal with this. Thanks.

Comment: is that what you want? [example](http://codepen.io/zeidanbm/pen/LErVXP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid both the image **and** the caption going outside the parent container, you have several options.  The nicest might be to set the image `max-height` and `max-width` to 100% and then to overlay the caption on the bottom.  If you want to keep them completely separate, you can do something like this:

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align:center;
}
#image {
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  max-width: 100%;
}
#caption {
  background: #282828;
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.fixedstars.com.au/images/runBack.jpg">
  <div id="caption">This is the caption</div>
</div>
```

This sets the maximum height of the image at100% less the height of the caption.  If you prefer for the caption to be stuck to the bottom of the container, even if the image is shorter, st the container to `position: relative` and give the caption `position: absolute; bottom:0;` for the container and the caption.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix this issue you have to set width and height to 100% for Image

Below is the complete demo.

Hope this will helpful to you.

```html
<style>
.mydiv {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80px;
}


.imgStyle {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<html>
<div class="mydiv">
<img src="http://www.boltoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/only-3d-natural-1024x768.jpg" class="imgStyle" />
Your Text Goes Here
</div>

</html>
```